# Cygwin & Bash: stdout redirect results in a '.' at the end of the file?

Tags: bash, cygwin, stdout

If I redirect the output of a linux command in Cygwin e.g.

```
ls -l > lsl.txt
```

the file lsl.txt gets created as expected

But if I do the same in a bash script and call it within Cygwin, what gets created is:

```
lsl.txt .
```

This file cannot be opened by most editors, and I'm assuming that operating on it or parsing it programmatically will be troublesome.

What causes this '.' to get appended to the file, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you show your bash script ?

Comment: At the end of the file *name*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to Windows line endings (CR-LF) in your bash script. Make sure you are using Unix line endings (LF).

Comment: How do I make sure my line endings are LF?

Comment: Here's a list of text editors with Unix newline support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison%5Fof%5Ftext%5Feditors#Newline%5Fsupport

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I discovered dos2unix which has done the trick. I may indeed switch editor in the longer term (currently using Sublime Text 2).